# access a value outside a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http, return

I am trying to fetch data from a url to my code.I am doing it in Service.js  Here is my code

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
.service('myService', function($http, $q) {

var v=0;

this.getdata = function() {
       $http.get('myurl').then(function(data) {
         v = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;

       });
      return v;  // how to return v from here(doesn't return the function's v)
     }
})
```

I want to use this in my AngularJS controller by calling the service :

```
  myService.getdata()//the v = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT needed here
```

But the problem is that the function returns 0(the v defined outside) instead of the value that I populate it with ! Is there a way that I could just process the Object returned from the URL and pass a single value and return it ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you are returning the `v` value before it's processed by the **asynchronous** `$http.get()` call, that's why you keep getting `0` as result.

Comment: @benderr : Will you please share some suggestions that how to resolve this type of errors ?

Comment: `this.getData = function() { return $http.get('myurl'); }` and then `myService.getData().then(function(data) { ... });`

Comment: you should be able to solve the issue using `promises`, I can't build an example right now, sorry

Answer (score 0):

> Use Ajax call

**Service**:

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
.service('myService',['$http', function($http) {

    this.getdata = function(entity){
        var promise = $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'services/entity/add',
            data : entity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            cache : false
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
        return promise;     
    };
}]);
```

**Controller :**

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
.controller('myctr',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
   myService.getdata().then(function(response){
            //Success

        },function(response){

            //Error         
        });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

$http.get method returns promise. This means that data is set to "v" variable after you have returned it. Thus you should get data only after promise is resolved. E.g.:

```
angular.module('demoService', [])
     .service('myService', function($http, $q) {
     var data = null;
     this.fetchData = function() {
         $http.get('myurl').then(function(data) {
             data = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;
        });
     }
     this.fetchDataNoSave = function() {
         return $http.get('myurl');
     }
     this.getData = function() {
         return data;
     }
})

angular.module('demoService').controller('ViewCtrl', function(demoService, $scope) {
    demoService.fetchDataNoSave().then(function(data) {
         $scope.v = data.data.Tweets[0].FAVOURITE_COUNT;
    })
    // OR
    demoService.fetchData().then(function() {
         $scope.v = demoService.getData();
    })
})
```

The difference in these options that the first one will not save state in the service and you will be ought to get this state every time. The second one manages state within service what means that every controller with injected service will have access to fetched data